# Method selection at compile time. What if the parameter can have several types?

Tags: java, methods, compilation, runtime, compile-time

I am led to believe that the java compiler does all the work of method selection at compile time (or am I wrong?). That is, it will decide exactly which method to use in which class at compile time by examining the class hierarchy and method signatures. All that is then required at run time is to choose the object whose method is to be called and this can only work **up** the inheritance chain.

If that is the case, how does this work?

```
int action = getAction ();
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder()
    .append("Hello ") // Fine
    .append(10) // Fine too
    .append(action == 0 ? "" : action); // How does it do this?
```

Here, the type of the parameter can be either `String` or `int`. How can it decide at compile time which method of `StringBuilder` should be invoked?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An expression such as

```
action == 0 ? "" : action
```

can have a single return type. The compiler understands this as an expression returning an `Object` instance. This, at runtime, can be either `String` or `Integer`.

In your case, `append(Object)` will be called. The StringBuilder implementation will then call `toString()` on the parameter, which will give you the expected result (either `""` or an integer value converted to String).

Comment: That makes sense. A hidden autobox is the only side-effect.

Answer (score 0):

[StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) has a many overloaded methods called append. So there is a different append for most type. Any other type is an Object.

```
StringBuilder   append(boolean b)
Appends the string representation of the boolean argument to the sequence.
StringBuilder   append(char c)
Appends the string representation of the char argument to this sequence.
StringBuilder   append(char[] str)
Appends the string representation of the char array argument to this sequence.
StringBuilder   append(char[] str, int offset, int len)
Appends the string representation of a subarray of the char array argument to this sequence.
StringBuilder   append(CharSequence s)
Appends the specified character sequence to this Appendable.
StringBuilder   append(CharSequence s, int start, int end)
Appends a subsequence of the specified CharSequence to this sequence.
StringBuilder   append(double d)
Appends the string representation of the double argument to this sequence.
StringBuilder   append(float f)
Appends the string representation of the float argument to this sequence.
StringBuilder   append(int i)
Appends the string representation of the int argument to this sequence.
StringBuilder   append(long lng)
Appends the string representation of the long argument to this sequence.
StringBuilder   append(Object obj)
Appends the string representation of the Object argument.
StringBuilder   append(String str)
Appends the specified string to this character sequence.
StringBuilder   append(StringBuffer sb)
```